# WordPress ignoring is_page() conditional

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<?php if( is_home()  || is_page(10)): ?> 
    <div class="text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php elseif(is_single() && !is_page(10)): ?>
    <div class="text-center col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
<?php endif; ?>
```

All I'm trying to do is change the classes assigned to this `<div>` if you are on a single post, which works fine, but I can't get it under control when viewing a contact page, which it seems to recognize as a single post. This is fine, but I want to exclude one page from this effect.

I've tried is_page('Contact'), is_page('contact'), and is_page(10)
None of them seem to return true in any case, I even deleted all other conditionals and just had it print something if its the contact page, but it still doesn't return true and has no effect.

I've done a lot of searching and all I can find says I'm using it correctly.. I'm at a loss as to why it wouldn't return true?

Am I using php if statements incorrectly and it's been an 'oops, it worked' scenario thus far? 
The url to the page ends with ?page_id=10, the page is titled 'Contact'

I could create a page template, but it seems more than what I need here, the contact page is painfully simple, and all I really need to do is center the four lines of text appropriately using bootstrap. Works fine across all other pages of the website, and changes the `<div>` appropriately if you're on the homepage or viewing a single post.

As requested, the full index.php code is below. Thanks to anyone who is willing to look at this. It is nothing massive, I am relatively new so please excuse my excessive commenting - I'm still learning.
Full index.php: https://pastebin.com/nnG0ny99

Comment: Can you confirm you are working with a Page, and not a Post? I just want to make sure because if its a post, you'll need to use is_single(10);

Comment: It is a page, I edit it under 'Pages' in word press. I previously tried is_single(10) as well though, just to be sure prior to coming here. It had no desired effect. The url ends with ?page_id=10 opposed to ?p=10 as well.

Comment: If possible paste your full code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using:

```
global $post;

<?php if( is_home()  || $post->ID == 10): ?> 
<div class="text-center col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php elseif(is_singular() && $post->ID != 10): ?>
<div class="text-center col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
<?php endif; ?>
```

That way you are getting the actual post id rather than the page id.

Edit: try to change `is_single()` to `is_singular()` as saNs suggested in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you recommended, and it still isn't changing the <div> classes accordingly. When I inspect the page the classes are assigned according to the elseif statement.

Comment: @ShaunReed see the edited answer, try changing `is_single()` to `is_singular()`

Comment: Still no changes. I updated the post with the full index.php and it includes my is_singular() changes.

Comment: @ShaunReed Are you working in single.php? Can you do a <?php die(); ?> to make sure the file you're working in is running?

Comment: @ShaunReed is is_page(10) returning true when you go to the desired page? The other thing you could try is getting the page id and evaluate that like: `get_the_ID() == 10` also try to check if `is_singular()` is returning true when you are on the actual page.

Comment: @rideron89 Can I remove this post due to embarrassment? *facepalm* it killed an unrelated page, which I'm assuming points me shamefully in the right direction! Thats a nice bit to test with. I'll remember that in the future. I'm going to move this code into the right place, and it _should_ work.

Comment: Haha no worries, I've spent my fair share of time working in the wrong template file :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not using is_page() in the loop.

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/
"Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop, is_page() will not work. In order to call it after The Loop, you must call wp_reset_query() first."

Comment: I saw this same bit of information on the exact page you linked, I don't believe it applies to this situation. I've posted my full index.php in a Pastebin above, please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are correctly posting is_page() outside the loop soo...

If your Wordpress theme has a "page.php" file that will be where you need to put the code. It might not be "page.php" but some sort of page template. You can learn more about template hierarchy here. Index.php is the catch all if there are no other templates for pages, posts, categories ect

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 1):

`is_single()` works  for "any post type, except attachments and pages"(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) So it will always evaluate to false for pages.

Use `is_singular()` instead.

Comment: Good to know, but didn't fix my issue :( News to me, though. Knowing this will probably save me some trouble in the future, thanks for the heads up!